# How do I define CRUD operations in a service (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, crud, angular-services

I have a problem with my CRUD operations in the service. When I click on Create Btn it is creating an object but it doesn't push the object in the table list.

Ctrl (where's the table list):

```
$scope.nameslist = CrudService.getAll();
```

Ctrl (for Modal dialog):

```
$scope.createItem = function (newObj) {
   CrudService.create(newObj);
   $scope.newObj = null;
   $scope.ok();
}
```

CRUD Service (it's a .factory):

```
...
return {
    getAll: function () {
       return resService.names.query();
    },

    create: function (newObj) {
       resService.names.save(newObj);
       //this.getAll.push(newObj); //this doesn't work
    }
...
```

Request Service (also a .factory):

```
...
return {
  names: $resource(baseUrl + '/api/names/:Id', {
      Id: '@Id'
  }, {
     'update': {
          method: 'PUT'
     }
  })
...
```

Can anyone help me? How can I push the new object in the table list?

Comment: Either you push your new item manually or call the getAll function again to get the updated item from server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've created the object you can push the object to the list or call getAll

```
$scope.createItem = function (newObj) {
   CrudService.create(newObj);
   $scope.newObj = null;
   $scope.ok();
   \\either
   $scope.nameslist = CrudService.getAll();
   \\or
   $scope.nameslist.push(newObj); // this assumes this is an array
}
```

UPDATE///
$broadcast sends messages down to child controllers whereas $emit sends them up.
using $rootscope.$emit first inject it into the controller

```
.controller('myCtrl' ['$scope', '$rootscope', function($scope, $rootscope ...
```

then you can use `$rootscope.$emit('added-Name')` or you can even add an argument so `$rootscope.$emit('added-Name', {newObj: newobj})`

then in the catching controller

```
$rootscope.$on('added-Name'), function(event, args) {
    $scope.namelist.push(args.newObj);
    //or if you're not passing the argument
    $scope.nameslist = CrudService.getAll();
});
```

using a Shared Service:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('sharedService', function(){
    var nameList = [];
    return{
        get: function(){
            return nameList;
        }
        set: function(val){
            nameList = val;
        }
        add: function(name){
            nameList.push(name);
        }
    }
})
```

inject the sharedservice into the controller
`.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'sharedService', function($scope, sharedService ....

fill the nameList in the service with `sharedService.set(CrudService.getAll());` and in $scope.createItem you could have `sharedService.add(newObj);`

then you can have a watch on the sharedService.get()

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
            return sharedService.get();
        }, function(newValue, OldValue) {

            if (newValue !== OldValue) {
                $scope.namesList = sharedService.get();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is this good practice? I thought this would be defined in the service?!

Comment: the get? then use your getAll(). That is the best way as you're keeping in sync with the server. I was just demonstrating that you could add the object directly into your list.

Comment: no I mean `$scope.nameslist.push(newObj)` Is there an opportunity to define this in the service?

Comment: The `$scope.nameslist` is in an other Ctrl as well than the `$scope.createItem`

Comment: ah i see. looks like you'll require some way of telling the table list Ctrl to get the list again. You could you $rootscope.$broadcast or $rootscope.$emit to send a signal throughout the app or you could have a service to hold the nameslist and $watch for changes.

Comment: I know. But how can I define it in my example? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Could you tell me how can I define $save instead of .save() in the service? I have tried `newObj.$save()` but it is displaying a error $save is not a function..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80885/discussion-between-dominic-scanlan-and-yuro).

Comment: I'm at work. I can't open the chat because of access rights. But when I'm at home I will send you a message ok?

Comment: sure thats fine but this is a fine blog about angularjs CRUD. http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/